# Инициализатор вложенного свойства

Tags: c#

Я не понимаю это баг какой то, или разработчики языка просто забыли добавить это свойство? В интернете по этому поводу только одна тема в которой ответа на этот вопрос так я и не нашел.

И так, при динамическом добавлении контролов на `TabControl`, я не могу обратится к свойству `FlatApperance` для кнопки.Возможно вы скажете, что контрол создается динамически и не понятно что создается: кнопка, текстбокс и тд. Но все должно быть понятно и ясно т.к. перед созданием самого контрола указывается его тип, и следовательно должны быть переопределены все свойства для этого типа.К примеру:

```
tabControl1.TabPages[$"page{i}"].Controls.Add(new TextBox()
    {
        Name = "tb_rec_title",
        Text = dr["title"].ToString(),
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI Semilight", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
        Location = new Point(23, 25),
        Size = new Size(300, 25),
        WordWrap = true 
    });
```

В данном коде создается текстбокс и ему присваиваются свойства, в том числе `WordWrap`, который не имеется к примеру у кнопки. И действительно, создавая кнопку нельзя обратится к этому свойству. Тогда в чем проблема, почему нельзя обратится к свойству `FlatApperance` для кнопки? Вот, что мне не понятно...

```
tabControl1.TabPages[$"page{i}"].Controls.Add(new Button()
{
    Name = "btn_img_back",
    Text = "<",
    Font = new Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 11, FontStyle.Regular),
    Location = new Point(406, 100),
    Size = new Size(22, 35),
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    /*FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White*/
});
```

Т.к. кнопка создается динамически, к нему нельзя просто так обратится, например как тут

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе текст ошибки, которую вам пишет IDE.

Comment: Имя "FlatAppearance" не существует в текущем контексте

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дело в том, что в синтаксисе

```
new C()
{
    name1 = value1,
    name2 = value2
}
```

`name1`/`name2` должны быть именами свойств и ничем другим. В вашем коде указано `FlatAppearance.BorderColor`, это не имя свойства.

Для вложенных свойств есть малоизвестный специальный синтаксис, в котором можно не создавать подобъект, а только указывать его свойства. Должно сработать так:

```
new Button()
{
    Name = "btn_img_back",
    // ...
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    FlatAppearance = // <-- тут НЕ указываем создание объекта
    {
        BorderColor = Color.White
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик: Пожалуйста!

Comment: я изучаю c# по книге Албахари, это моя 2-ая книга по языку, почему то я не встречал вложенные свойства, возможно не дошёл до этого момента, а возможно забыл, но это очень вряд ли.Эта фича в какой версии была добавлена?

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик: Затрудняюсь сказать, я помню этот трюк с палеолита (версия 3.5).